# WPF and Blend: Resizing window doesn't work

Tags: wpf, blend

I've set a storyboard to enlarge and shrink a window. These work fine in the Blend editor, but when actually running, they just don't work at all.

The window is supposed to expand/shrink at the same rate horizontally as vertically.

What's the fix to this?

[image]

Here's my XAML.

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="32" Width="32" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="GrowFrame">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="window">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="32"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="256">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Amplitude="0.25"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="window">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="32"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="256">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Amplitude="0.25"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="window">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Amplitude="0.25"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="window">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="White">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                    </EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingColorKeyFrame>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ShrinkFrame">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="window">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="256"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="32">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="window">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="256"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="32">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="window">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.5">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="window">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="Transparent">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingColorKeyFrame>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource GrowFrame}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ShrinkFrame_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ShrinkFrame}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
</Window>
```

Comment: Post the code you tried so far...

Comment: Blender produces some markup called xaml when you set the properties. If you could identify it and update the question, we can try to figure out if any of the properties you set is wrong.

Comment: @sankarann There we go.

Comment: Is the storyboard works when you directly run from Blend? Since you have set the Windows resizing as no resize...

Comment: @Sankarann "No resize" means that the user cannot resize the form by dragging its borders.

Comment: That's fine.. Its working when run from Blend?

Comment: @sankarann Yep, it looks fine as a preview in Blend.

Comment: What about the run mode.. Is the same project you open it in blend?

Comment: @sankarann Yep. If I hit "run project" in the Blend editor it does what is shown in the image.

Answer (score 2):

WPF does support both synchronized animations (as you attempted) and overlapping animations where you supply a HandoffBehavior.  You might try that to see if it works as a workaround.  However I think this is a known bug (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/715415/window-width-height-animation-in-wpf-got-broken-on-net-framework-4-0).  I'm shocked it has not been fixed by now.

Comment: This is reassuring: "Thank you very much for your feedback. At this point we are not going to be making any changes in this area of the product. Thanks! Wpf Team"

Comment: Right, and considering how long it has been since, they are holding true to their words.  I don't think they understood the implications.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there's a bug in the new framework releases that prevents synchronous animation.  However, here's a quick little solution that works very well for me.  It's beyond simple, so I don't think any explanation is in order.  It works, and that's all that matters:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="App.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="32" Width="32" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None"
    MouseEnter="MouseEntered" MouseLeave="MouseLeft">
</Window>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace App
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private const int MAX_WINDOW_SIZE = 256;
        private const int MIN_WINDOW_SIZE = 32;
        private const int ANIMATION_SPEED = 10;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MouseEntered(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            while (this.Width <= MAX_WINDOW_SIZE)
            {
                this.Width += ANIMATION_SPEED;
                this.Height += ANIMATION_SPEED;
            }
        }

        private void MouseLeft(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            while (this.Width >= MIN_WINDOW_SIZE)
            {
                this.Width -= ANIMATION_SPEED;
                this.Height -= ANIMATION_SPEED;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does work. Though, after a little more searching, I found that animating Window's width and height DO work in .NET 3.5... Why not in 4.5.1? Seems like a bug.

Comment: @SuperDisk Hmm, not sure.  I did quiet a lot of research and couldn't find a solution that would fix this issue.  The solution I've provided is what I've been using myself -- sometimes simple way is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, just use a fixed sized transparent window as a workaround:

```
   <Window x:Name="window" x:Class="RectangleWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="RectangleWindow" Height="300" Width="300"  ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" 
            Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="True">
        <Window.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="GrowFrame">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="insideRectangle">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="32"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="256">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Amplitude="0.25"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="insideRectangle">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="32"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="256">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Amplitude="0.25"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="ShrinkFrame">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="insideRectangle">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="256"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="32">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="insideRectangle">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="256"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="32">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Window.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource GrowFrame}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ShrinkFrame_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ShrinkFrame}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Window.Triggers>

        <Rectangle x:Name="insideRectangle" Fill="White" 
          Width="50" Height="50"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
                <DropShadowBitmapEffect/>
            </Rectangle.BitmapEffect>      
        </Rectangle>
    </Window>
```